# Fonts missing in WinForms.FontDialog

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts

When I display an instance of WinForms.FontDialog (C#, .NET 2.0), I am missing some fonts that I expect to be there (e.g. Courier, Fixedsys, MS Sans Serif). Also, a customer is complaining that Adobe fonts he has installed are also not showing up in the list.

How can I get these fonts to display in this dialog?

Answer (score 6):

FontDialog was designed to only show TrueType fonts to stay compatible with GDI+.  Getting it to show the device fonts takes a bit of Reflection hacking:

```
using System.Reflection;
```

...

```
FontDialog fontDialog1 = new FontDialog();

MethodInfo mi = typeof(FontDialog).GetMethod("SetOption", 
    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        mi.Invoke(fontDialog1, new object[] { 0x40000, false });
fontDialog1.ShowDialog();
```

I don't know whether this also enables Adobe's OpenType fonts, I don't have any.  Let us know.

Comment: Wont this raise a 'Not a Valid Font Exception' as GDI+ Supports only true type fonts.

Comment: Of course, expectation is that the OP does something else with them.

Comment: Is there any override so that a font dialog only displays valid true type fonts.

Comment: `FontDialog was designed to only show TrueType fonts to stay compatible with GDI+`