# Fill ComboBox with List of available Fonts

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts, windows-xp

How can I fill a combo-box with a list of all the available fonts in the system?

Comment: Please have a look at these examples (http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/GUI-Windows-Form/Loadallsysteminstalledfonts.htm)(http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/GUI-Windows-Form/Loadallsysteminstalledfonts.htm), (http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/GUI-Windows-Form/Fontlist.htm)(http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/GUI-Windows-Form/Fontlist.htm).

Comment: @thelost the link no longer exists

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You can use `System.Drawing.FontFamily.Families` to get the available fonts.

```
List<string> fonts = new List<string>();

foreach (FontFamily font in System.Drawing.FontFamily.Families)
{
    fonts.Add(font.Name);
}

// add the fonts to your ComboBox here
```

Comment: I installed Montserrat font. This code does not list the Montserrat fonts, but Microsoft Word does and Control Panel Appearance and Visualization does list the font as well. So what is wrong? Download URl of font is  https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/montserrat

Comment: I got it. This code list only TrueType fonts, see this fix http://stackoverflow.com/questions/329225/fonts-missing-in-winforms-fontdialog

Answer (score 12):

Not sure why we need to `foreach` here.

```
IList<string> fontNames = FontFamily.Families.Select(f => f.Name).ToList();
```

Comment: I wondered.  But then since it's an enumerable, isn't a `foreach` still needed? Or is there a C# syntax for something like `python`'s generator?

Comment: `IList<string> fontNames = FontFamily.Families.Select(f => f.Name).ToList();`

ComboBox don't accept `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 4):

Use Installed Font Collection class:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.text.installedfontcollection.aspx

This is alternative and equivalent approach to answer from Zach Johnson.

```
List<string> fonts = new List<string>();
InstalledFontCollection installedFonts = new InstalledFontCollection();          
foreach (FontFamily font in installedFonts.Families)
{               
    fonts.Add(font.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the easy way to do it. It includes two comboboxes 1 for the font name and one for the font size

```
 public FontFamily[] Families { get; }


 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        foreach (FontFamily oneFontFamily in FontFamily.Families)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(oneFontFamily.Name);
        }

        comboBox1.Text = this.richTextBox1.Font.Name.ToString();
        comboBox2.Text = this.richTextBox1.Font.Size.ToString();

        richTextBox1.Focus();

    }

private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

         float size = Convert.ToSingle(((ComboBox)sender).Text);

        richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font(richTextBox1.Font.FontFamily, size);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please keep in mind all will come from "System.Drawing"

```
foreach (System.Drawing.FontFamily font in System.Drawing.FontFamily.Families)
{
    comboBox1.Items.Add(font.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ComboBox1.ItemsSource = new InstalledFontCollection().Families;
```

and for the first time selected item:

```
private void Combo1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox1.Text = "Tahoma";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just bind like this:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static Fonts.SystemFontFamilies}}"
```