# Obtain installed fonts as a list

Tags: c#, .net, fonts

is there any way I can obtain installed fonts as a list (or array, but I prefer a List).

So like a method that will out all installed fonts to a list.
I have so far created this

```
List<string> fonts = new List<string>();
fonts.AddRange() //I don't know what to put in those brackets to obtain fonts.
```

Can someone provide a better way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fill ComboBox with List of available Fonts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426089/fill-combobox-with-list-of-available-fonts)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You want the [`InstalledFontCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.text.installedfontcollection.aspx) class:

```
using System.Drawing.Text;
using (InstalledFontCollection fontsCollection = new InstalledFontCollection())
{
    FontFamily[] fontFamilies = fontsCollection.Families;
    List<string> fonts = new List<string>();   
    foreach (FontFamily font in fontFamilies)
    {
       fonts.Add(font.Source);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a more simple way (First create a list box) -

```
using InstalledFontCollection col = new();
foreach (FontFamily fa in col.Families)
{
    ListBox.Items.Add(fa.Name);
}
```

Be sure to add! -

```
using System.Drawing.Text;
```