# How can i create combo boxes which i can choose my font with C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts

I have a richTextBox with some text (for example: Hello world). My aim is to make 2 combo boxes which i can choose a font and font size. The richtTextBox should change the font for the whole text.

For example: [image] that is from Word.

It will be nice when someone can tell me how can i begin that or what must i search in google. I search now a whole day and find only posts with the font dialog.

I use Visual Studio with WindowsFormsApplication

Question:

How can I make the combo boxes in C# like on the picture?

With friendly wishes sniffi

Comment: Have a look at this [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yf5t4e8(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: This question is broad. Tell us which environment WPF, WinForms, Web etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not too hard. You need to find all fonts installed on the current machine, populate the combo box with them, and when the user selects an item from the combo box you change your font depending on the selection.

To find installed fonts: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8657854/4795214

Answer (score 2):

Yo can use `InstalledFontCollection`.

On the load:

```
InstalledFontCollection IFC = New InstalledFontCollection();
ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
ComboBox1.DataSource = IFC.Families;
```

You will have the combo with all the fonts, and displaying its name.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using WPF you can do it with one line of code :

```
  <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static Fonts.SystemFontFamilies}}"/>
```

This line will generate a combobow with all fonts present in SystemFontFamilies.

Comment: OP hasn't specified whether he wants it for WPF and/or XAML

Comment: Sry i´m new at C#, i develop with Visual Studio and WindowsFormsApplication.

Comment: OP states explicitly he is using winforms, not WPF