# Creating a comboBox with all available fonts (from C# to C++/CLI)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, combobox, c++-cli

I'm trying to create a combobox and populate it with a list of all fonts available in the system. I had a look at this topic-->[Fill ComboBox with List of available Fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426089/fill-combobox-with-list-of-available-fonts) and I found the following code in C#:

```
     List<string> fonts = new List<string>();

        foreach (FontFamily font in System.Drawing.FontFamily.Families) 
         {        
           fonts.Add(font.Name); 
         }
```

I tried to convert it to something like this in C++/CLI:

```
List<string> fonts = gcnew List<string>();

             foreach (FontFamily font in System::Drawing::FontFamily::Families)
             {
                 fonts->Add(font->Name);
             }
```

But it didn't work. Can someone help me convert that C# code to C++/CLI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by this [site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.fontfamily.families.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1) ,You may write like this:

```
list<string>* fonts = new list<string>();
System::Collections::IEnumerator^ myEnum = FontFamily::Families->GetEnumerator();

while (myEnum->MoveNext())
{
    FontFamily^ oneFontFamily = safe_cast<FontFamily^>(myEnum->Current);
    fonts->push_back(oneFontFamily->Name);
}
```

`fonts` here is a pointer, something does not exist in C#, be aware!

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Just had to convert oneFontFamily->Name to std::string