# List all fonts and colors in menu flyout in windows store 8.1 app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I want to fill menu flyout with all available fonts and colors.I find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426089/fill-combobox-with-list-of-available-fonts)

but this is not working no such namespace System.Drawing there . How to achieve that in windows 8.1 apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For known/named colors you could use the `GetNamedColors()` or `GetColorNames()` methods from my toolkit [here](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit/WinRTXamlToolkit.Shared/Imaging/ColorExtensions.cs). For fonts I think you might be able to list them with DirectWrite as it's done [here](https://github.com/christophwille/winrt-snippets/tree/master/EnumerateFonts).