# Access OTF font

Tags: c#, fonts, truetype

I try to use **OTF** font installed on my system but I failed:

```
FontFamily family = new FontFamily(name_for_my_font);
```

I have tried to list all my fonts in system and indeed I haven't seen required font:

```
foreach (FontFamily font in System.Drawing.FontFamily.Families)
{
Console.WriteLine(font);
}
```

But I can see my font in **Fonts** folder. It has **OTF** extension. Maybe that is the problem? I can see only **TTF** fonts. But why? How can I access OTF font from my program?

UPDATE: Sorry the problem is with **OTF** access but not **TTF**! I have made corrections in my answer

Comment: It is the other way around, System.Drawing can handle only TrueType fonts, not OpenType fonts.

Comment: wow! I haven't no idea about that. So how can I access my OTF fonts?

Comment: There's an easy and a hard solution for that.  The easy one is stop trying to use OpenType fonts because they are never going to work in a Winforms app.  The hard one is to throw away everything you have and switch to WPF.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fonts missing in WinForms.FontDialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/329225/fonts-missing-in-winforms-fontdialog)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that OpenType fonts come in several flavors, one based on TrueType outlines and another based on PostScript Type 1 outlines. The Windows GDI+ graphics API does not support PostScript type 1 outlines. This is kind of ironic as the OpenType font format was created by Microsoft as a result of not being able to license some font technology from Apple.

So if a Windows application is based on GDI+ it will not be able to render OpenType fonts having PostScript type 1 outlines or PostScript type 1 fonts for that matter. Unfortunately `System.Drawing` is implemented using GDI+. Your only option is to stick to fonts using TrueType outlines.

(Or, if you are really desparate, you can P/Invoke to "classic" GDI and render the font into a bitmap.)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the System.Drawing.Text.InstalledFontCollection http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.text.installedfontcollection.aspx

Comment: 1) How that can help me to access my OTF font? 2) I can not see my font using your approach too.

Comment: This is still a good answer for how to see the installed fonts.  I am probably going to have to Pinvoke so I appreciate the step up on being able to list the font.